# Introducir valores en un manytomanyfiels

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

tengo una relación entre dos clases ***manytomanyfield***, en la segunda necesitaría poner un valor por cada nutval.
Por otro lado al intentar crear una columna mas en la segunda clase, no llega a agregarse en la bd, después de hacer las migraciones.
gracias
Este es el models.py

```
    
    class Nutinf(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        unit=models.CharField(max_length=5)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name='nutinf'
            verbose_name_plural='nutinfs'
    
         def __str__(self):
            return self.name
      
    
    class Products(models.Model):
        name_product=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        description=models.TextField()
        nutval=models.ManyToManyField(Nutinf)
        active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name='product'
            verbose_name_plural='products'
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name_product
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el problema, por favor actualiza tu pregunta explicando con mas detalles tu problema.

Comment: se necesita mas detalles, aunque una forma que podrias hacer lo es con un simple ForeignKey, utilizando Inline formsets.

Comment: La primera tabla son cargas nutricionales y en la segunda son productos, esto últimos tienen que tener un valor por cada carga nutricional seleccionada para el producto.EJEMPLO cargas: azucar, sal, hidratos.   1 producto: bollo: azúcar 30gr, sal 10gr, en este caso solo se seleccionaría dos cargas